# Angular: after restoring original data via function "angular.copy" the classes of elements are canceled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem when I press the Storno button. After pressing button Edit, first is saved the original data in scope. When I press button Storno to get the original data, they are restored from the original data. It is OK. Unfortunately, it restores the original template too. Class mycolor which is assigned to the element tr is canceled.

```
Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/kzu7J/3/
```

html:

```
 <div ng-app="app">
   <table>
      <tbody ng-repeat="person in people">  
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{person.id}}
          {{person.firstName}}
          {{person.lastName}}
          <button ng-click="myEdit($index)">Edit</button>
        </td>  
      </tr>
      <tr id="id_{{$index}}" ng-show="text_mod[$index]=='update'">
        <td>
          First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="people[$index].firstName">
          Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="people[$index].lastName">
          <button ng-click="myStorno($index)">Storno</button></td>              
      </tr>
      <tbody>  
    </table>      
  </div>    
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TodoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.people = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "firstName": "Peter",
      "lastName": "Jhons"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "firstName": "David",
      "lastName": "Bowie"
    }
  ];

  $scope.myEdit = function(index) {
    if(!$.isArray($scope.originalData)) { 
      $scope.originalData = [];
    }  
    $scope.originalData[index] = angular.copy($scope.people[index]); 
    addClass(index); 
  }    

  $scope.myStorno = function(index) {
    $scope.people[index] =  angular.copy($scope.originalData[index]);
  }    

  /* It works, but it is not a suitable solution
  $scope.myStorno = function(index) {
    $scope.people[index].firstName = $scope.originalData[index].firstName;
    $scope.people[index].lastName = $scope.originalData[index].lastName;
  }    
  */

  addClass = function(index) {
    var el = $('#id_' + index);
    el.addClass('mycolor');
  }    
}]);
```

css:

```
.mycolor {
  background: #3ec3ec;  
}
```

Function myStorno only restores data, but the background is changed back to white. Can you please edit this source to element keeps its class "mycolor" after copy original data into scope?

It is just a demo example. In fact, I have a biger problem that this property destroy design my real web page seriously.

Comment: Please include the code in your question rather than at an external site.

Comment: OK. I added code in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use an optional tracking function to associate the objects in the collection with the DOM elements. It is a new extension in AngularJS 1.2 like:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="person in people track by person.id">
```

The result: DOM elements won't be repeatedly destroyed and created and CSS changes will be kept so long as the data in the model exists.

Answer (score 0):

why not just add the class to the `<td>` in the html?

```
<td colspan="4" class="mycolor">
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/kzu7J/4/

You don't need the addClass function:

```
addClass = function(index) {
   var el = $('#id_' + index);
   el.addClass('mycolor');
}
```

Comment: In this case, it is possible. But the real code is more complicated. The problem is, why it affects the class when the scope is changed.

Comment: It is not recommended to have view logic inside your controller. If you want to dynamically set the class on your UI, have a look at ng-class. For more info, see: https://coderwall.com/p/r3_geg

Comment: I use the source code of another supplier. They use their own classes in my html (the change is dynamic). But the angular destroy these classes. I do not know why. Function myStorno changed only the scope...

Comment: You should never perform DOM manipulation inside a controller. This is a fundamental concept. You should have your HTML inside Views and the controller should request the Views as appropriate. In your View or HTML you can do your conditional styling using ng-class. The supplier needs to buy into this way of working too.